# accessibility android Skip nav links are not working

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have added skip to main content links on header in my web app. It works as expected in Windows and MacOS. It even works as expected in IPhone. But the same is not working in Android chrome/talk back.

when I check further, This skip nav links are not working even in webaim.org . The code I refer https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/web-accessibility-skip-navigation-links/

Could someone please help why android chrome is having this issue? Is it a browser behavior? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze what is happening in this scenario.

> 1) TalkBack sets `ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS` to the element

This is very important, notice that this says `ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS`not `FOCUS`. For a hidden skipnav link to become visible it needs to get `FOCUS` as marking the element as visible (or perhaps shifting it on screen) with the :focus pseudo selector is a very common implementation of this. It's very important that such a control receives `FOCUS`, which it never does with TalkBack.

> 2) The user double taps to click the element they just heard get focus.

When the user activates the control a physical click event is set to the middle of the onscreen focus rectangle for the control. Similar to actually touching the screen.

> 3) The browser sees a physical click event occur on the page.

TalkBack essentially has blindly sent a mouse down event to an area of the page that has nothing or perhaps another control overlayed with this invisible element. Either way, the thing that the browser wanted to click was never "visible" because it never properly obtained `FOCUS` only `ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS` and so the control is not there to be clicked.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detailed response.

Comment: Was there an aspect of this that didn't get addressed? If not you should upvote and accept the answer. If there is, clarify your question! :)

Comment: Sorry. I am not able to mark this as answer :( I guess I need more reputations to do so.

Comment: @ChrisCM Is there any workaround for the skip nav links on Android Talkback? I understand that the current implementation is to respond to web's `FOCUS` event and there's no way to respond to `ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS` at the moment but is there any workaround that you or your colleagues are implementing for Android Talkback? I'm currently having trouble with implementing a solution, similar to the question I had with Android Talkback not responding to onFocus